# Create multidimensional array with index by variable

Tags: javascript, oop, object, multidimensional-array

I'd like to do this:

```
var array=new Array();

//I have an array
//[0]{category:'1',page:'2',row:'3',column:'4',description:'boh',id:'0'};
//[2]{category:'2',page:'2',row:'4',column:'4',description:'bah',id:'2'};

//for cycle for order the original object
object.forEach(function(obj){
```

The problem is here: how can i set the indexes of this multi-dimensional array by object values?

```
    array[category][page][row][column] = obj;

}

//then with another cycle
for(var a=0;a<category.length;a++){
    for(var b=0;b<page.length;b++){
        console.log(array[a][b][c][d].description);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not totally clear what you are trying to do. What is `category` array?  or `object` in  `object.forEach` ? Would help to define your data input better and show expected results

Answer (score 1):

```
you can create multi dimentional array bu this

var myarray=new Array(3)
for (i=0; i <3; i++)
    myarray[i]=new Array(5)
```

Comment: i can't use it for my objective, because i don't know the array size.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed!

```
var FunzioniDB = function () {

this.elenco_prodotti = function (callBack) {
    var data = [];
    var testo_query = 'SELECT cat_varianti,colore_tasto,id,descrizione,prezzo_1, categoria, pagina, posizione FROM prodotti WHERE descrizione!="" AND prezzo_1 !="" AND posizione!="" AND pagina!="" AND categoria!="" ORDER BY posizione ASC,categoria ASC,pagina ASC ;';
    var prom = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        comanda.sincro.query(testo_query, function (prodotto)
        {
            //DARE LA CONDIZIONE CHE ESISTA IL PRODOTTO
            resolve({prodotto: prodotto});
        });
    });
    data.push(prom);
    Promise.all(data).then(function (data) {

        /*data.forEach(function (oggetto) {});*/

        var array_prodotti = data[0].prodotto;
        //struttura oggetto
        //prodotto è l'oggetto principale
        var prodotti = new Array();
        array_prodotti.forEach(function (ar) {

            var split = ar['posizione'].split('-');
            //console.log(ar);

            var riga = split[0];
            var colonna = split[1];

            if (prodotti[ar.categoria] === undefined)
            {
                prodotti[ar.categoria] = new Array();
            }

            if (prodotti[ar.categoria][ar.pagina] === undefined)
            {
                prodotti[ar.categoria][ar.pagina] = new Array();
            }

            if (prodotti[ar.categoria][ar.pagina][riga] === undefined)
            {
                prodotti[ar.categoria][ar.pagina][riga] = new Array();
            }

            if (prodotti[ar.categoria][ar.pagina][riga][colonna] === undefined)
            {
                prodotti[ar.categoria][ar.pagina][riga][colonna] = new Object();
                prodotti[ar.categoria][ar.pagina][riga][colonna] = ar;
            }
        });

        var output = '';

        for (var a in prodotti) {
            for (var b in prodotti[a]) {
                for (var c = 1; c <= 6; c++) {
                    for (var d = 1; d <= 8; d++) {
                        //output += prodotti[a][b][c][d].descrizione + ',';
                        console.log(a + '-' + b + '-' + c + '-' + d);
                        if (prodotti[a][b] !== undefined && prodotti[a][b][c] !== undefined &&
                                prodotti[a][b][c][d] !== undefined)
                        {
                            console.log('prod.esist');
                            output += '*' + prodotti[a][b][c][d].descrizione;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        callBack(output);
    });
};
};         });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following (2-dimensional in example):

```
var multiArr = [];

yourInputArrOfObjects.forEach(obj => {
  if (!multiArr[parseInt(obj.category)]) {
    multiArr[parseInt(obj.category)]=[];
  }
  if (!multiArr[parseInt(obj.category)][parseInt(obj.page)]) {
    multiArr[parseInt(obj.category)][parseInt(obj.page)] = obj;
  }
});
```

This will allow you to access the first object through

```
multiArr[1][2];
```

Please note that this approach does what you want, but creates a lot of 'waste' or empty items in arrays or subarrays: arrays always start from 0, so if you have e.g. only page 9, than multiArr contains empty (undefined) entries for numbers 0-8.

A better approach could be to create a function with a filter:

```
function giveMeObjectAtMultiIndex(indexObj) {
  var outArr = multiArr.filter(item => {
    return (item.category == indexObj.category && item.page == indexObj.page));
  }
  return outArr[0];
}
```

to get the object with category==1 and page==2, you do:

```
objSought = giveMeObjectAtMultiIndex({category: '1', page: '2'});
```